# Como fazer atualizar um dado quando a data inserida for igual a data atual?

Tags: php, html, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou fazendo um sistema onde o usuário pode agendar postagens, ou seja, se ele inserir a data e a hora, a postagem vai ser liberada quando a data atual for igual a inserida, até ai a lógica é simples mas estou com problemas para aplicar isso a uma função.

Assisti uma [videoaula](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUh0v56LrQ8) porém é bem antiga e utiliza parâmetros que não consegui usar então adaptei o código mas mesmo assim não funciona.

A função está assim:

```
function publicarAgendado(){
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
  $dataAgora = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');

  $selecionar_agendados = @mysqli_query("SELECT * from postagens where status = 0");

  while ($PubAgd = @mysqli_fetch_array($selecionar_agendados)) {
    $aiai = $PubAgd['id'];
    setlocale(LC_TIME,'pt_BR','pt_BR.utf-8','portuguese');
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    $data_banco = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($PubAgd['agendado']));
      if ($data_banco <= $dataAgora) {
        $up = mysqli_query("UPDATE postagens SET status=1 where id= $aiai");

      }

   } 
}
```

No banco o campo dessa data está como datetime e no HTML está em um input com o tipo datetime-local. Por favor me ajudem urgente pois tenho que entregar uma prévia desse sistema amanhã.

Comment: Bem-vinda Julia, saiba que é sempre bom marcar uma resposta como aceita, caso ela resolva seu problema. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Supondo que o link de conexão ao banco de dados é:
>
> `$conn = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "Nome_DB");`

1. Basta usar  `date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');` apenas uma vez no inicio do PHP.
2. Nas querys (select e update) falta o link da conexão com o banco de dados `mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT...` e `mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE`
3. Retorne a data do banco no formato original e configure a `dataAgora` no mesmo formato, ou seja `$dataAgora = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`
4. No mais o código correto é:

   ```
   function publicarAgendado(){

       $conn = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "Nome_DB");

       date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
       setlocale(LC_TIME,'pt_BR','pt_BR.utf-8','portuguese');

       // data compativel com a data do banco
       $dataAgora = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

       $selecionar_agendados = @mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from postagens where status = 0");

       while ($PubAgd = @mysqli_fetch_array($selecionar_agendados)) {
          $aiai = $PubAgd['id'];
          //basta retornar a data do banco no seu formato original
          $data_banco = $PubAgd['agendado'];

          if ($data_banco <= $dataAgora) {
             $up = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE postagens SET status=1 where id= $aiai");
          }

   }

   //Execução normal automatica
   publicarAgendado();
   ```

> OBS:não use `$dataAgora = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');` para comparar com `$data_banco = date('d/m/Y H:i:s, strtotime($PubAgd['agendado']));` que não vai funcionar em datas do mesmo dia com horário anterior ao horário atual. A explicação? Não sei. Fiz teste e constatei!

[date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) Configura o fuso horário padrão utilizado por todas as funções de data e hora em um script.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite,

Faça desta forma e verifique se foi resolvido:

```
$data_banco = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($PubAgd['agendado']));
```